# Access Face Set color in bpy

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the face set color of a polygon via python?
The face sets are new to Blender sculptmode, I like to transfer face set color to sculpt vertex colors.

bpy.ops.sculpt.face_sets.. has operators, but there is no way to access the data like obj.data.face_sets..

Answer (score 2):

Blender 3.4 lets you access sculpt face sets via a custom int data layer.
I don't think you can get the color itself yet, but can access the face set index like this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
custom_data_layer = bm.faces.layers.int.get('.sculpt_face_set') 
for face in bm.faces:
    print(face[custom_data_layer])
```